# How to get the information from the iframe displayed (ClickJack) to the user back to the attacker?

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, html

Just for knowledge I want to know how to get the information from the i-frame displayed to the user back to the attacker?

**Scenario :**

Suppose You are an attacker and you want to grab the private information of users that is displayed on a web page only to them.
So, You find a clickjacking vulnerability on that Web Page and decide to use
it to grab the private information of the users .

Supposing that the Web Page is: http://domain.com?data=12

Now, When Victim's open that ClickJack page his/her information should be sent to attacker.

I tried to make js code but It was working fine if ClickJack page is located on the same host.
It was not working to an external Website.

**Have you any idea how I could create that ClickJack Page?**

Comment: Typically clickjacking gets the user to trigger an action which you want them to do but which they wouldn't do otherwise.

Comment: I do not think you fully understand how [clickjacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking) really works.

Answer (score 0):

How about sending the information the the local server and then using a back-end technology (PHP?) to send it to the 3rd party server?

Your browser is preventing this as a security measure (AJAX Call to a 3rd party server)

Comment: Welcome to Information Security Exchange.  You're encouraged to provide thorough Answers, and not respond with a question.  This type of response should be a comment.  You can get reputation needed for a comment by submitting Edit suggestions on questions/answers, or asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:  You don't.  As you saw, your attempt to get information from the iframe back to the attacker worked when the parent and the iframe were from the same domain.

When the domains are different, the information in the child iframe cannot be read by the parent.  See [Same-Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

For clickjacking, the parent frame would provide an invisible layer using javascript that  hovers over controls in the child so when a legitimate user tries to click on legitimate controls in the child frame, they are actually clicking on controls the attacker provides.  [This is why clickjacking is also known as UI Redressing.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking)